# The type or namespace name 'Http' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net' **when compiling with mono**

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, mono, httprequest, raspberry-pi3

First of all, I did look into all the questions referring to the error *error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Http' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net'(are you missing an assembly reference?)* here on StackOverflow, but my case is a little different.

I have this application that uses Http requests to communicate with a Web API 2  (simple numbers, coordinates). Both applications work perfectly when run on Windows. However, for my project, I need to run the application from the terminal of  **Raspberry Pi 3**.

I tried compiling it with Visual Studio, with and without adding MONO in the *Conditional compilation symbols* field. - **It runs from terminal but the buttons, listboxes do not react**

I compiled it in several different ways, both on windows and on Raspbian Jessie (the OS of the RPi 3):

```
$ **mcs -pkg:dotnet *.cs**  
$ **mcs *.cs**  
$ **C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe /t:exe /out:DroneApp.exe *.cs**  
$ **mcs -out:hello.exe hello.cs**  
$ **dmcs ./*.cs -r:/usr/lib/mono/4.0/System.Web.dll**
$ **xbuild /p:Configuration=Release DroneApp.csproj**
```

and any other way that I could find on the internet (I've spent 2 days doing this so I can't remember all of them).
I also want to state that I installed the packages mono-devel, mono-complete, eferenceassemblies-pcl, ca-certificates-mono (which deal with Http requests) and mono-xsp4 (for ASP.net applications).

**Nothing works :(**

All the classes that are used as services to communicate with the server throw me the error *The type or namespace name 'Http' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net'* even though I triple checked that all my references are in place.

The target framework of my app is .NET Framework 4.5.

[check this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3v5tE.png)

If you have even a small idea or if I should provide some more information, please help me. Thank you.

Example of one of the service classes that throws the error (all of them are the same)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

namespace DroneClientApp.Services
{
    class PathService
    {
        private const string UserEndPoint = "api/Paths";
        private const string RequestResponseFormat = "application/json";

        private readonly string _serverUrl;

        public PathService(string serverUrl)
        {
            _serverUrl = serverUrl;
        }

    public async Task<List<Path>> GetPathsAsync()
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(_serverUrl);
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(RequestResponseFormat));

            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(UserEndPoint).ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Path>>().ConfigureAwait(false);
            }

            return await Task.FromResult(new List<Path>()).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }enter code here
```

Comment: Please check out list point (1.) here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and then consider adding actual code.

Comment: "I have this application that uses Http requests" : Please show this code.

Comment: Sorry. I added now the code.

Comment: what version of mono are you using?